# Memory issue with Swift and CGPath

Tags: swift

I built a (struct) wrapper around CGPath in Swift, to test it, I built a loop (that executes 10 million times) that adds lines to the path :

```
for _ in 1...10_000_000 {
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 10, y: 20))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 20, y: 10))
        path.closeSubpath()
        }
```

The problem is that after some time (less than a minute), the app crashes and there is no break point, and actually, very little information in the console :

> Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

But what's weird is that, sometimes, for some unknown reason, it logs more info about the issue :
[image]

What should I do ? Can this error happen if there isn't enough memory ? Or can it be something else ?

Thank you.

**EDIT : Actually, it really seems to be the fact that there isn't enough memory, of course that's understandable, but I didn't thought that would produce this error code.**

Comment: Yes, you are running out of memory. And that's a typical thing to see when you run out of memory. What error code did you expect?

Comment: @KurtRevis Thank you ! I thought there would be a much more descriptive error/warning such as "App received memory warning".